# Colon after function declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am going through source code of Vue.js. In almost all the function declarations I find a new way of defining functions

```
function isStringStart (chr: number): boolean {
  return chr === 0x22 || chr === 0x27
}
```

Can somebody explain me what is this kind of function declaration called?

Comment: It's a type declaration.

Answer (score 7):

That's a type declaration. `:boolean` means basically, that the `isStringStart` function must return a `boolean` value. The same with the argument's type declaration. `chr: number` means, that the function accepts one argument, which has to be typeof number.

If the requirements are not fulfilled (not proper arguments are passed or wrong value is being returned), the typechecking library you are using will throw an error.